# MVC 5 - Adding Client Validation to refuse the default value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, client-side-validation

I'm using a `DropDownListFor` and provide a default selection of `-- Select Make --` which has an empty value. I want to provide the user with a hint of what to do (thus the 'Select Make') but don't want to allow them to actually submit that value. Currently the website allows this to go through.

I thought that adding a minimum length of 2 would prevent it but no luck.

I'm fairly new to .NET MVC so let me know if I'm doing this in the completely wrong way.

The actual POST request body is:

```
Make=&OtherArgument=1&NextArgument=test
```

View code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Make)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Make, Model.Make, "-- Select Make --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Make)
```

Model code:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Make = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Deere",
            Value = "Deere"
        },
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Case",
            Value = "Case"
        },
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "CAT",
            Value = "CAT"
        }
    };
```

Comment: Either remove the Default parameter or check for the value of the selected dropdown in jquery

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell. You seem to have a value of 'OtherArgument' being posted, but from what you've shown it's not clear where that would be coming from. Maybe I'm just not seeing something obvious.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee If I remove the default parameter then the dropdown automatically selects the first option. I don't want this as the user is more likely to submit the form without changing the option (I want to force them to pick).

Comment: @MikeC. You're right, the form has other fields (e.g. `OtherArgument`) that are being filled out but are not in the above code.  All of the other fields pass their values through.

Comment: I see. Actually I just read what you had up there incorrectly. Sorry about that, just ignore my comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first issue here is the distinction between the ***model selected*** and the ***models*** that a user can select. 
Adding the `ModelSelect` property to your model solves this (and some view changes).

The second issue is enabling jquery unobtrusive validation by adding the script references.

These are the steps you need to take to get this working with javascript validation preventing form submission (assuming MVC4+).

**Model**

```
    public class AModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string SelectedMake { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Make = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Deere",
                Value = "Deere"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Case",
                Value = "Case"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "CAT",
                Value = "CAT"
            }
            };
    }
```

*Note the SelectedMake property*

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Make)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.Make, "-- Select Make --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedMake)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

*Note SelectedMake in the first param for the dropdown and the ValidationMessageFor*

**Script references**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

*Needed to enable jquery validation*

**Screen grab**

[image]

*Note the red asterix, jquery unobtrusive now prevents the form submission.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger the client-side validation, the input has to be within a `<form>`, and depending on version(MVC 3 and earlier), specifically using `@Html.BeginForm`.

If that's not the problem, can you post more of the view?

Comment: More info [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

in the model all you have to do is set an allowed range with an annotation.  The "default value" is 0 so set your range to 1 to maxint.  You will throw a model error if they don't choose something.