# Select default value in Dropdown from Database MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdown

I have a dropdown and I want to select first value from Database.

Model :

```
  public Model(int? ID)
    {
        if (ID> 0)
        {
            var leaveSearch = Entity.LeaveSearch(ID);
            if (leaveSearch != null && leaveSearch.Count > 0)
            {                   
                PeriodID = leaveSearch[0].PeriodId;                  

                if (MonthYearList == null || !MonthYearList.Any())
                    MonthYearList = new SelectList(Entity.Period(), "iPeriodID", "Period", PeriodID);
            }
        }
      
    }
```

View :

```
            @Html.DropDownListForValidationRight(model => model.PeriodID, Model.MonthYearList,"Select", new { @class = "dropDown selectpicker"})
```

Type a message

Comment: Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674796/mvc-5-adding-client-validation-to-refuse-the-default-value)

Comment: If you want the first data to be selected by default, set the option label without values.

Comment: @MehranGharzi can you specify more ?

Comment: `    Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PeriodID, Model.MonthYearList)
`

Comment: use order by Entity.LeaveSearch(ID).OrderBy(x=>x.PeriodId); then remove select from html helper Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PeriodID, Model.MonthYearList)